# bash: :/usr/X11R6/lib:/usr/local/lib: No such file or directory

Tags: bash

I started to install ns2, and after that any time I open the terminal I get this message

bash: :/usr/X11R6/lib:/usr/local/lib: No such file or directory

Any idea?!

I added to this to my bashrc

```
# LD_LIBRARY_PATH
OTCL_LIB=/home/Apps/ns-allinone-2.35/otcl-1.14
NS2_LIB=/home/Apps/ns-allinone-2.35/lib
X11_LIB=/usr/X11R6/lib
USR_LOCAL_LIB=/usr/local/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$OTCL_LIB:$NS2_LIB
:$X11_LIB:$USR_LOCAL_LIB

# TCL_LIBRARY
TCL_LIB=/home/Apps/ns-allinone-2.35/tcl8.5.10/library
USR_LIB=/usr/lib
export TCL_LIBRARY=$TCL_LIB:$USR_LIB

# PATH
XGRAPH=/home/Apps/ns-allinone-2.35/bin:/home/Apps/ns-allinone-2.35/tcl8.5.10/unix:/home/Apps/ns-allinone-2.35/tk8.5.10/unix:/home/Apps/ns-allinone-2.33/xgraph-12.2/
NS=/home/Apps/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/
NAM=/home/Apps/ns-allinone-2.35/nam-1.15/
export PATH=$PATH:$XGRAPH:$NS:$NAM
```

Comment: What did you modify in your shell startup scripts (`.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `.profile`, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to install the NS-2 but the lines that you have added to the `.bashrc` file are slightly wrong. Instead you have to add the following lines in the `.bashrc` to set the environment variables (remember to replace `/path_to/` with the location where you have extracted the ns; by looking at your post it is `/home/Apps/`):

```
# LD_LIBRARY_PATH
OTCL_LIB=/path_to/ns-allinone-2.35/otcl-1.14/
NS2_LIB=/path_to/ns-allinone-2.35/lib/
USR_Local_LIB=/usr/local/lib/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$OTCL_LIB:$NS2_LIB:$USR_Local_LIB

# TCL_LIBRARY
TCL_LIB=/path_to/ns-allinone-2.35/tcl8.5.10/library/
USR_LIB=/usr/lib/
export TCL_LIBRARY=$TCL_LIBRARY:$TCL_LIB:$USR_LIB

# PATH
XGRAPH=/path_to/ns-allinone-2.35/xgraph-12.2/:/path_to/ns-allinone-2.35/bin/:/path_to/ns-allinone-2.35/tcl8.5.10/unix/:/path_to/ns-allinone-2.35/tk8.5.10/unix/
NS=/path_to/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/
NAM=/path_to/ns-allinone-2.35/nam-1.15/
export PATH=$PATH:$XGRAPH:$NS:$NAM
```

After this you have to restart your system or you may use

> source ~/.bashrc

to reload the `.bashrc`. Now run the `ns` and you will get the `%`.

You may want to refer to this blog for installation instructions http://installwithme.blogspot.in/2014/05/how-to-install-ns-2.35-in-ubuntu-13.10-or-14.04.html

Comment: Strictly speaking, `PATH` doesn't need to be explicitly exported in a user's init scripts -- since it's already present in the environment variable, the shell will copy any updates through to the environment without extra steps.

Comment: You have to explicitly export these variables while installing NS-2 else it will not work.

Comment: I don't question that the variables need to be specified. I don't question that *some* of them need to be explicitly flagged for export. `PATH`, however, does not need to be explicitly flagged: `PATH=$PATH:$XGRAPH:$NS:$NAM` would work without the `export` in front of it just the same.

Comment: Agreed; it would work both with and without `export` prefixed to `PATH`.